# List users of an array of roles

Tags: user-roles

I'm able to list users by a single role only. When I try and add an array to the code below I just get a list of all authors. I'm sure that it is something straight forward that I'm missing.

Thanks

Josh

```
 <?php

            $roles = array('guest-teacher', 'president', 'core-faculty');

   $args  = array(
     'meta_key' => 'last_name',
     'role'     => $roles
    );

    $wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
    $wp_user_query->query_orderby = str_replace( 'user_login', 'lsjs_usermeta.meta_value', $wp_user_query->query_orderby );
    $wp_user_query->query();

    $authors = $wp_user_query->get_results();



    // Check for results;
    if (!empty($authors))
    {
        echo '<ul class="permanent">';
        // loop trough each author
        foreach ($authors as $author)
        {
            // get all the user's data
            $author_info = get_userdata($author->ID);
            $url = get_author_posts_url($author->ID);  

    ?>


        <h3><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"><?php echo $author_info->last_name; ?></a></h3>

            <?php
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    } else {

    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot pass an `Array` of User Roles to `WP_User_Query`. The `role` argument only accepts a String, which is then cleared by a `trim` command.

See [user.php on Line 495](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/user.php#L495), where `prepare` handles the Query for the Constructor after parsing the `$args`.

Comment: Hm, I am not sure about that - try `-role`, but I think it won't work.